# Paragraph Indention not working

Tags: formatting, indentation

I have included the package to indent the first line of each paragraph but it is not working in my paper. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,hidelinks,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{breakcites}
\usepackage{float}

%Import the natbib package and sets a bibliography  and citation styles
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}} %Citation-related commands
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{\linespread{1}\selectfont}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts, amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % full-width
    \topskip        =   20pt
    \parskip        =   10pt
    \parindent      =   0 pt
    \baselineskip   =   15pt



\usepackage{setspace}               % line spacing
    \onehalfspacing
\usepackage{adjustbox}              % resizing
\usepackage{caption}                % to reset the cations etc 
\usepackage{rotating}               % for the sidewaystable
\usepackage{booktabs}               % neatly formatting lines
\usepackage{dcolumn}                % aligning decimals
    \newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\usepackage{natbib}                 % bibliography
%% \bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\newcommand{\sym}[1]{\rlap{#1}} % for the stars


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{autobreak}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more reasonable example file would be

```
\documentclass{article}

    \topskip        =   20pt
    \parskip        =   10pt
    \parindent      =   0 pt
    \baselineskip   =   15pt

\begin{document}

One two three. One two three. One two three. 
One two three. One two three. One two three. 
One two three. One two three. One two three. 
One two three. One two three. One two three. 
One two three. One two three. One two three. 
One two three. One two three. One two three. 


One two three. One two three. One two three. 
One two three. One two three. One two three. 
One two three. One two three. One two three. 
One two three. One two three. One two three. 
One two three. One two three. One two three. 
One two three. One two three. One two three. 
\end{document}
```

Producing

[image]

if you remove the settings of `\parskip` and `\parindent` you will obtain the default indented layout

```
\documentclass{article}

    \topskip        =   20pt
%    \parskip        =   10pt
%    \parindent      =   0 pt
    \baselineskip   =   15pt

\begin{document}

One two three. One two three. One two three. 
One two three. One two three. One two three. 
One two three. One two three. One two three. 
One two three. One two three. One two three. 
One two three. One two three. One two three. 
One two three. One two three. One two three. 


One two three. One two three. One two three. 
One two three. One two three. One two three. 
One two three. One two three. One two three. 
One two three. One two three. One two three. 
One two three. One two three. One two three. 
One two three. One two three. One two three. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

In general, avoid randomly copying lines in to the preamble. Always start from an empty preamble and just add packages when needed.  Once you get an over large preamble with lots of unusable code such as repeated packages, it makes it hard to spot the code that is affecting the document.